# Running python script multiple times with different arguments read from a text file

Tags: python, text, automation

So i have a python script that takes an argument of a location and runs the script accordingly.

I want to speed up the process so rather than waiting for each run to finish and then entering the second argument (location).

Is there a way to enter all arguments in a text file like so:

```
    C:\a\b
    C:\a\c
    C:\a\d
```

and then get python to run each one individually?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make a loop and iterate through the file names. So it will be something like this:

```
with open("arguments.txt") as fp:
    for filename in fp:
        with open(filename.strip()) as file:
            # do stuff with the file
```

EDIT:

```
with open("arguments.txt") as fp:
    for filename in fp:
        filename = filename.strip()
        # now you can pass the filename to your function
```

Comment: I have tried this but i am getting the following error when i run it:

IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: '"\\\\lGup-002\\SFQ\\brands\\Releases\\ss\\16.43\\Intenal 7\\15-09-2016"\n'

Comment: Yea try it now, I fixed it when your typing the traceback, sorry forgot to strip() And you don't need " when you're storing the filenames

Comment: I added .strip() method but I receive the same error.

Comment: and did you get rid of the quotation marks inside the file of filenames? To make it simple, how *did* you store them?

Comment: use a `/` instead of \\ to make it simple

Comment: This is how i have it

with open("arguments.txt") as fp:
    for filename in fp:
        with open(filename.strip()) as file:
            print 'yes'

Comment: no....inside your `arguments.txt`, whats in that? I believe you stored the file paths wrong

Comment: \\lGup-002\SFQ\Brands\Releases\ss\16.43\IInternal 7\2017-03-07

In my text file i have links that look like above, the purpose is to pass it as an argument to another script and then do it for all others. This is link points to a network location so i would need to paste it as it is for simplicity reasons as there will be hundreds of them to paste in to notepad

Comment: ok, and are you sure that \\lGup-002\SFQ\Brands\Releases\ss\16.43\IInternal 7\2017-03-07 actually exists? note: there's two \\ in the beginning. And that `2017-03-07` is a file, not a directory.

Comment: Yes it is on a network drive so it 100% exisits and to prove that when i paste the link in a windows explorer it opens. I appreciate your time and efforts btw

Comment: Its a directory not a file so the arguments i am giving are directories**

Comment: when you said *"i have a python script that takes an argument of a location"* couldn't you just gave that *python script* the `filename` instead of opening the filename? I thought you wanted to open that file and do stuff with it. ie. see my edit

Comment: Sorry for my miscommunication. That worked fine. Thank you so much

Comment: Well my bad for not understand your problem earlier, your welcome, good day.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question right, you want to enter arguments that are listed in directory?

For that purpose you can use `os` with the following commands

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
mypath = 'C:\a\'
files = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
files
>>> ['C:\a\a', 'C:\a\b', 'C:\a\c']
```

This will give you a list of directory locations.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, the directory is the argument

Comment: Now you only have to loop through the files in your python script.